# One part is getting compiled first

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am getting data from firestore then representing it using a custom component in react-native but the problem is that return function is getting compiled before I get the data from firestore

```
async function getdata(){

  const Ref = db.collection('restaurants');
  const snapshot = await Ref.get();

  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  friends.push(doc.data());
  });

  }


const ListScreen = () => {
  
  getdata()

return (
  <FlatList
    keyExtractor={friends => friends.Name}
    data={friends}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return (
        <View>
        <ImageDetail
        Name={item.Name}
        Building={item.Building}
      /> 
      </View>
      );
    }}
  />
);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and store `friends` in state like so:

```js
const ListScreen = () => {
  const [friends, setFriends] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getdata(){
      const Ref = db.collection('restaurants');
      const snapshot = await Ref.get();
      const friendsArray = [];
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        friendsArray.push(doc.data());
      });
      setFriends(friendsArray);  
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={friends => friends.Name}
      data={friends}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <View>
            <ImageDetail
              Name={item.Name}
              Building={item.Building}
            /> 
          </View>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

In that case you've initialized `friends` as an empty array using [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), and you call `getData` to retrieve the restaurant data from Firestore when the component mounts by passing the empty array to [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Once the data are retrieved, `friends` is set to the new data and the component re-renders with your Firestore data.